# Unable to upload to $web from GitHub actions

Tags: azure, github-actions, cicd, azure-static-website-hosting

I'm in the process of deploying our `Flutter Web` app to storage account within Azure, this particular storage account has had the Static website option enabled, doing so creates a `$web` container for me to deploy my site, uploading my files works perfectly fine and I'm able to see the website.

When I try to automate this with CICD is doesn't allow / can't see the `$web` container, if I switch out `$web` for a test container it works.

Does anyone know or even seen this issue before when trying to deploy a static website to the $web container, below is the part of the workflow file that does the upload:

```
 - name: Deploy to Azure Storage Static Website
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        azcliversion: 2.0.72  # Use the desired Azure CLI version
        inlineScript: |
          az login --service-principal --username ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }} --password ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET }} --tenant ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          az storage blob upload-batch --destination "\$web" --destination-path . --source build/web
      env:
          AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTION_STRING }}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to **[This Document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-how-to.md)**,  the **`$web`** container is a reserved container name for static website hosting in Azure Storage. When you enable static website hosting, Azure Storage creates this container for you automatically. **`$web`** is the Default root container that is used to store static websites files. And,

> According to this [github comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/4752#issuecomment-339743136) by **williexu** forward slash is not supported in the blob root container. The files on the first level will be the only ones uploaded by `upload-batch` because blobs in subdirectories have names that include their path from the container. You need to utilize a non-root container if you want to upload files in batches recursively.

And This document - [Use GitHub Actions to deploy a static site to Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-static-site-github-actions?tabs=userlevel) also ***uses `-d '$web'` without forward-slash***. I referred the github action workflow and steps from this Document below:-

***My github workflow:-***

```yaml
on: [push]

name: AzureLoginSample

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Login to Azure
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
    - name: Upload to blob storage
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        inlineScript: |
            az storage blob upload-batch --account-name valleystrg98  --auth-mode key -d '$web' -s .
```

***Output:-***

[image]